# How to instruct Google Test to expect std::abort()?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I am using Google Test on code I expect to fail. As part of this failure the code calls a custom assert macro, which contains `std::abort()`.

Unfortunately Google Test's `EXPECT_EXIT()` is not "catching" the `std::abort()`.

This is a self-contained example to emulate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// A placeholder for my assert macro
void MyFunction()
{
    std::abort();
}

TEST(TestGroup1, TestName)
{
    EXPECT_EXIT(MyFunction(), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(SIGABRT), ".*");
}
```

I get this failure output:

```
Death test: MyFunction()
    Result: died but not with expected exit code:
            Terminated by signal 6 (core dumped)
Actual msg:
[  DEATH   ]
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: I needed to use `::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGABRT)`

Comment: I use expect_death

Comment: @user997112 You should post that as an answer to your question, it would be more useful for people in future looking for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use `::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGABRT)`